# Socrata catalog Search API Beta - Page broken links

Tags: search, beta, catalog, socrata, soda

In Socrata catalog Search API Beta, links property seem to be incomplete for some "page" resource type.
For example in:
http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?&domains=data.cityofnewyork.us&only=pages
many of the resource "link" property are incomplete
link: "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/view/"
Most of these pages also seem to exists under a different "id" in the public web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out! I've filed a bug with our engineering team to fix the bad links.